# why delegate cannot add a listener with a reference in container

Tags: c#, reference, delegates

I create an <int,delegate> dictionary and add a delegate object into the container.
And try to add another listener method into that delegate which get the reference by TryGetValue method of Dicionary.
The result shows that we cannot output the event handler 2, why?

```
class Program
{

    public delegate void TestDelegate();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, TestDelegate> delegates = new Dictionary<int, TestDelegate>();
        delegates.Add(1, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("event handler 1");
        });
        if (delegates.TryGetValue(1, out TestDelegate td))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"delegates same Reference {ReferenceEquals(td, delegates[1])}");
            td += () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 2");
        }
        delegates[1] += () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 3");
        if (delegates.TryGetValue(1, out TestDelegate td2))
        {
            td2.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are immutable objects. The `+` operator returns a new delegate instance, whose invocation list contains the two delegates which were added together.

You do:

```
delegates.TryGetValue(1, out TestDelegate td);
td += () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 2");
```

That copies the reference to the delegate from the dictionary into `td`. `td += ...` then combines the invocation list of `td` with the new delegate you specify into a new delegate instance, and stores a reference to that new delegate instance inside `td`.

So, we've updated `td` to point to a new delegate instance, but we haven't updated the reference held in `delegates[1]`. When we access `delegates[1]` later in order to invoke it, that instance's invocation list won't contain `() => Console.WriteLine("event handler 2")`.

---

`strings` are similar: they're references to immutable objects. Consider:

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2 = s1;
s2 += ", World";
Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

That prints "Hello": the `+` created a new string instance and assigned it to `s2`, but we didn't update `s1` to refer to that new string instance, and we didn't mutate the string which `s1` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

`td += () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 2");` can be expanded to:

```
td = td + () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 2");
```

So you can see that you are simply reassigning to a local variable, rather than updating the original delegate instance, which incidentally is immutable.

---

On the other hand, when you do this:

```
delegates[1] += () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 3");
```

It is expanded to this:

```
delegates[1] = delegates[1] + () => Console.WriteLine("event handler 3");
```

So you are *replacing* the value in the dictionary with a *new* delegate, that is a combination of the original plus a new handler.